# How do I save and change the name of some Excel tab automaticaly with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to create new sheets based on an bigger excell file.
I would like to rename the files like "nameofthesheet_Vouchering Hours August 2022_YTD" for each sheet, currently I am only getting "nameofthesheet". How can I change the code in order to have it like this?

```
Sub Separar_guias()
Dim xPath As String
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
xWs.Copy
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The above code does not **change the sheets name**. It exports each sheet as a new workbook with the respective sheet name. So, what do you want accomplishing? The same as the existing code, but with a different name, or only change the respective workbook names? Then, "nameofthesheed" I suppose should be the existing name (`ws.Name`. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I think I did not express me very well. I have this code that saves each tab of my excel file with the name of the tab, I would like to save it with the name of the tab + something else at the end for every tab in the file.

Comment: Then, use `Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & "_Vouchering Hours August 2022_YTD" & ".xlsx"`... Do you want also giving a signification to `August 2022_YTD`? I mean to be the current month of the current year and separated by "_" a string composed by something else (year, day etc.)?